# how to change "media/k2/items/cache/" to another folder - K2 Joomla?

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I use the k2 plugin on Joomla. I want to change the default cache image URL.

From: "media/k2/items/cache/"

To: "images/items/cache/"

Please help me.